# Code Sign Error : Distribution iphone App

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

I have an iOS project to open and when i open it i get an error -

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: x' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

What i have now is a file named given to me by the project owner-

```
CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest
```

But i dont know what to do wit it. I created a CA and all that but i cant get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so here are detailed steps on how to distribute. You seem new to the topic:

1. You want to request a development and **distribution** certificate in Keychain Access (I see you have done that) and upload it to developer.apple.com (you are part of the developer member program right?)
2. Create an app ID (in provisioning profiles)
3. Create a distribution certificate - make sure this and step 2 follow your bundle ID
4. Download the profile and drag to Xcode
5. Go to your Xcode project, in the target or project build settings set your code signing option to the Distribution certificate (which must match your Bundle ID and of course your distribution and development certificate)
6. Now go to edit scheme -> then change from debug to release
7. Set to build for an iOS device (or none at all)
8. Go to product -> Build For -> Build For Archive
9. Scroll down on the side (your classes tab etc.) to the product which should be named (AppName.app) and show it in finder.

   Create an application on iTunes Connect

   Compress the .app and load it to Application Loader

   Send it off!

Answer (score 1):

You need to public and private key for the provisioning profile you are using.
The person how created the certificate with which the provisioning profile is signed will have to supply you with them.